# Should the tense of predicate in main clause be the same as the tense of predicate in the relative clause?

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

It is a very basic question that I need to be confirmed. Consider the following sentence (taken from a book titled *Essential Japanese Grammar* by **Masahiro Tanimori** and **Eriko Sato**).

> スミスさんが昨日見た学生は背が高かった。

The relative clause スミスさんが昨日見た modifies 学生 with past tense. The main clause also uses past tense 高かった.

If I translate it to English, it becomes

> The student whom Smith saw yesterday was tall.

For me it sounds a bit awkward because the student may no longer be tall now.

## Question

- Should the tense in relative clauses agree with the tense in main clause?
- Compare to the previous one, what is the difference in meaning and nuance for スミスさんが昨日見た学生は背が高い。?

Comment: Several months ago when I started learning Japanese, I have read this sentence and I did not spot the awkwardness until I read it just now for the second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Japanese, the tenses don't need to agree, and in fact, **tense mismatches can serve an important purpose**.

In English, we have a wide variety of verb tenses, i.e., 3 (past present future) x 4 (simple progressive perfect perfect-progressive) = 12 basic time tenses.  Japanese learners of English sometimes wonder why we have so many.

However, consider the following:
"I have not heard that before"
聞いた事がありません

The English version uses perfect present.  The Japanese version uses mixed tenses (聞いた is past, ありません is present).  **So sometimes mixed tenses in Japanese give us additional time-tense flexibility**, the same way that the non-simple tenses give us in English!

On a side note, the English non-simple tenses actually have "mixed tenses" hidden in them.  E.g., in "have not heard", the "heard" is actually a past-like form called the "past participle", but "have" is present tense.

Answer (score 3):

No, tense doesn't need to agree beyond clauses.

The original sentence refers to smith's memory, rather than a permanent fact. That's why it adopts past tense.